# TCP Reset Attack - Documentation

Tags: tcp, documentation

Which is the 'official' research paper which firstly describes the TCP reset attack? I've already found a lot of research papers which talk about it or about solutions, but I am interested in the 'first one'. Do you know when it was discovered?

Answer (score 1):

***History About Tcp Rest:***

1. 1981: The Transmission Control Protocol (TCP) is specified in Request for Comment (RFC) 793.
2. 1985: Bob Morris points out **vulnerabilities** in TCP.
3. **1994**: The first publicized **manipulation of TCP vulnerabilities** occurs when Kevin Mitnick uses the so-called **Christmas Day attack** to hit security expert Tsutumo Shimomura.
4. 1995: Paul Watson posts an advisory on TCP vulnerabilities on Usenet. The advisory receives a significant attention. A number of investigations follow, especially in the field of sequence number generators.
   Plus:A prototype **"Buster"** software package was demonstrated in 1995 that would send forged resets to any TCP connection which used port numbers in a short list.
5. 1995: Laurent Joncheray presents a paper on the topic "**Simple Active Attack against TCP**" at the Usenix conference.
6. 2001: Cert describes a vulnerability in various TCP/IP sequence number generators and points to the window size issue.
7. 2003: Paul Watson shows that attacks are quite easy to perform even using a simple DSL connection.
8. **the open source Snort used TCP resets to disrupt suspicious connections** as early as **2003**.
9. The IETF considered TCP resets by firewalls, load-balancers and web-servers harmful in RFC3360.
   Plus:In 2004: The IETF (Internet Engineering Task Force) publishes an initial version of the Internet draft "Improving TCP's Robustness to Blind In-Window Attacks".

---

***Tcp Rest Controversy Events:***

1. Comcast Controversy:**By late 2007**, **Comcast** began using **forged TCP resets** to cripple **peer-to-peer** and **certain groupware applications** on their customers' computers.This started a controversy, which was followed by the creation of **the Network Neutrality Squad (NNSquad)** by Lauren Weinstein, Vint Cerf, David Farber, Craig Newmark and other well-known founders of and champions of openness on the Internet.
2. In **2008**, the NNSquad released **the NNSquad Network Measurement Agent**, a **Windows software progra**m written by John Bartas, which **could detect Comcast's forged TCP resets** and **distinguish them from real endpoint-generated resets**. The technology to detect the resets was developed **from the earlier open-source "Buster" software** which **used forged resets to block malware and ads** in web pages.
3. In **January 2008**, the **FCC** announced it would **investigate Comcast's use of forged resets**, and, on **August 21, 2008**, it ordered Comcast to **terminate the practice**.

I seek some article about tcp-rest attack and I found your question ,it is my founding about this.Maybe would help U.:)